# Output counted list with extra qualifier

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I currently have a table with the following columns:

`Comm ID`   `Item Name` `Months`    `Orichalcum`    `Tempest Jade`  `Green Iron`    `Weltsilver`    `Ambergelt` `Beggar's Lye`  `Dragonbone`    `Iridescent Gloaming`   `Total Materials`   `Commissioned By`   `CSID`  `Ordered On`    `Ordered For`   `Materials Provided`    `Money Provided (c)`    `Artisan ID`

To get a list that shows how many entries with a matching `Item Name` there are in an ordered list I use the following:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(Commissions!B1:B&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 order by count(Col2) label count(Col2)'Count'",1))
```

This works great and outputs a list like:

```
Item Name           Count
Biting Blade        1
Bloodcloak          1
Bullroarer's Shout  1
Butcher's Cleaver   1
Captain's Mask      1
```

I now want the same list but I want to only count entries that also have particular text inside the `Ordered On` col. I've tried working this out, but can't seem to find the correct syntax. (I also want to take the text it is looking for from a particular cell on a sheet rather than being hard coded at some stage)

Comment: Welcome. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you need is:

```
=QUERY(Commissions!B1:O,"select B,  count(C) where (B != '' and O = '"&B3&"') group by B order by count(C) label count(C)'Count'",1)
```

Please notice how we reffer to the cell `'"&B3&"'` so as to include it in our query.

I prepared for you a [working sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ondv2_ezrHbONaQwh8AIFbtrTns0qb9CdlKSITc4GSg/edit#gid=624049730) using cell `B3`. To the cell is added a drop-down validation for easier use.

Comment: Lovely, thank you! I thought I had tried that notation, but I must have had an error in my syntax.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with your other queries as well. Have a look at my sheet.